# Execute bash code from HTML to running docker command

Tags: php, html, bash, docker, shell

I have a bash code like this:

```
sudo docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash -c 'cp test1.txt test2.txt'
rm test3.txt
```

It worked well in terminal. But I want to call it from html. My html code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>run bash</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
   $output=shell_exec('sh /Users/path/script.sh');
}
?>
<p><?php echo $output; ?></p>
</body>
```

Basically, I want to click the button "submit" (the php code I put above will be called by another html file) and it will execute the bash code to login to docker and run the command `cp test1.txt test2.txt`.

But it only deleted test3.txt while it didn't copy the file on docker when I ran it from html. Also, I didn't get any output from website. This was weird cause it could work in terminal just by `sh /Users/path/script.sh`.

I am new to both html and docker. Will be really appreciate it if anyone could give me advice.

Comment: From your posting, it is not clear to me what exactly is the content of `script.sh`. Is it the two lines (`sudo` and `rm`) you wrote on top of your question?  Aside from the remarks given by Dave, note that running the command in the way you did it, `script.sh` is not executed by bash. It may not matter in your simple case, but it could be important if you put into your script bash-specific features.

Comment: yes `script.sh` was the two lines (sudo and rm). sorry I didn't make it clear.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest coming up with a different way to invoke this task.  It's very easy to use a `docker` command to root the entire host; if you're not already comfortable with the Docker CLI or invoking shell commands this way, it's fairly easy to accidentally introduce a major security vulnerability.

Comment: @yuhangchen: If copying did not work, you should at least get an error message. I suggest running the copying with `bash -cx 'cp -v .....'` and catch stdout **and** stderr from your shell_exec and display the result on your HTML page for debugging.

Comment: @user1934428: I got the error "the input device is not a TTY".

Comment: This is odd. I don't see in your code, where reading from a tty would be requested, but this is probably a starting point for researching waht is going on, because in terminal, you do have a TTY, while when started from your web page, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are executing docker with "sudo" you'd need the command to be executed via `shell_exec()` with sudo as well.

Furthermore, if your server environment uses chroot, the docker binary might not be even available to the user running the PHP process.

I suggest checking with your system administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried in terminal that without 'sudo' it still work. And I heard that executing a command as root with shell_exec is not secure. btw, I don't know what chroot means. I just did this on localhost and using mac.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to allowed ( probably www-data user ) to use sudo without password for this one script.
You can do this via sudoers:

`vim /etc/sudoers`

Add line:

`<user>        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/script.sh`

Then your shell_exec should looks like this:

`$output=shell_exec('/usr/bin/sudo /path/to/your/script.sh');`

But be careful, use sudo only if know what you are doing ;)

I also suggest to print output using "pre"

`<pre><?php echo $output; ?></pre>`

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I followed your suggestion but it still didn't work form html.

Comment: I got the error 'the input device is not a TTY'. I guess my problem was not caused by sudo.

Comment: So try without “-t”

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was not about `sudo`.
To get the stdout, I ran this

```
<pre><?php echo exec('sh /path/to/my/script/script.sh 2>&1', $output, $return_var); ?></pre>
<pre><?php print_r($output); ?></pre>
<pre><?php echo $return_var; ?></pre>
```

Noted that when an error occurs during the execution, or the process does not produce output, `shell_exec()` will return NULL. Therefore, using function `shell_exec()` cannot detect whether the process is successfully executed by the return value. If you need to check the exit code executed by the process, use the `exec()` function instead.

It outputed `the input device is not a TTY`.

And in my bash script, I changed `sudo docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash -c 'cp test1.txt test2.txt'` into `docker exec -i container_id /bin/bash -c 'cp test1.txt test2.txt'`.

Basically, running `docker exec -i` rather than `docker exec -it` fixed my problem.